# How can I improve a stereo calibration using openCV, python and bundle adjustment?

Tags: python, opencv

I have calibrated a stereo pair of cameras using openCV (openCV 3.4.1 and python 2.7) -
my end goal is to derive a point cloud from image pairs. I actually have a third camera in this scene, and am also considering a workflow handling all three at once (or three stereo pairs...), but for now I am concentrating on one stereo pair.
The images are legacy data that I can't reshoot, so I can't for example get better calibration images. I'll admit I am not hugely familiar with the openCV library.

I want to refine the stereo result, possibly using bundle adjustment, but I dont know how to acheive that with opencv python, or perhaps another python library.

Each camera was calibrated individually, but with one of a matched pairs of images.

I used the following flags for camera calibration:

```
cam_flags = cv2.CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO + \
            cv2.CALIB_FIX_PRINCIPAL_POINT + \
            cv2.CALIB_ZERO_TANGENT_DIST
```

The resulting calibration was evaluated by plotting the reprojection error:

```
for i, op in enumerate(objpoints):
    ip2 = cv2.projectPoints(op, rvecs[i], tvecs[i], mtx, dist)[0]
    p = (ip2 - imgpoints[i]).reshape(2, -1)
    ax.plot(p[0], p[1], 'x', lw=0, ms=8)
```

an example plot shows what I feel is a good calibration:

reprojection error:

[image]

Moving on to the stereo calibration, I call the stereoCalibrate function, with the flag:

```
sflags = cv2.CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC
```

This option gives me the best results compared with allowing all camera parameters to be adjusted, or leaving just the distortion coefficients to be recalculated.

When I evaluate the stereo calibration, I rectify a pair of images and plot lines on top of the undistorted images:

```
[RL, RR, PL, PR, Q, roiL, roiR] = cv2.stereoRectify(
    L_m, L_d, R_m, R_d, (720, 1280), R, T, flags=0, alpha=0)
```

The plots look quite reasonable:

rectified images:

[image]

However, if I transform the target points to 3d:

```
R = cv2.Rodrigues(rvec)[0]
p3d = R.dot(op.T) + tvec
```

there is a visible gap between the two targets, of approximately 5-6mm in real world units.

3d projection:

[image]

To me, this seems like a problem in evaluating the focal length of the camera to the necessary degree of accuracy... So I come back to my question. How can I improve the result? I believe bundle adjustment is an appropriate method (I have seen the scipy cookbook least squares camera recipe, for example), but I am uncertain how to implement that for a stereo pair to improve each camera's intrinsics, and R and T.

Many thanks for any advice.